# Random assignments with 95% confidence of at least $K$ duplicate assignments

Tags: statistics, sampling

I'm running an experiment online.  Of my $N$ test questions, each participant sees $M$ (randomly selected, $M < N$).  If I want a minimum of $K$ responses to each question, how can I calculate a reasonable sample size (with, let's say $95\%$ confidence that I'll have $K$ responses to each question).

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on the distribution of the number of questions answered, which you don't know. Try it on a small group and extrapolate.

Comment: This question looks very hard to get an exact answer for.  If you give a range of values for $N$, and $K$, then close approximations might be available to you.  Also, $M$ is what you are trying to calculate, right?